# Regex email(several types) extraction

Tags: regex

I'm tring to extract email adressess from a content. I've a problem about false positives.

My regex for: example@site.com

```
[^\.^\w+](\w+) *?@ *?(\w+) *?(?:\.|dot) *?(\w+)
```

Regex for: example@sub.site.com

```
[^\.^\w+](\w+) *?@ *?(\w+) *?(?:\.|dot) *?(\w+) *?(?:\.|dot) *?(\w+)
```

I want the first regex not to match with:
example@sub.site

How can I fix it?

Comment: Your regex will match `$abcd      @   xyz .  anycombination123xyz` but not `with+inside@my-domain.com`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to distinguish example@site.com and example@sub.site is to maintain a list of valid top level domains (yes, I'm sorry).

i.e, replacing your last `(\w+)` by `(com|org|info|ly|...` and so on.

[There is no universal way.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Also, you could do only one regex.

Also, my address could be example@sub1.sub2.site.com, be careful...